# Testing Gradle Plugin That Uses project.gradle.projectsEvaluated

Tags: unit-testing, gradle-plugin

I am trying to test a Gradle plugin that uses the [BuildAdapter#ProjectsEvaluated](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/BuildAdapter.html#projectsEvaluated-org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle-) function to allow custom configurations and dependencies to be added to my project.  The problem that I'm having is that if I evaluate the project using InternalProject#evaluate in the junit test then the projectsEvaluated function is never called.  If I switch to the more robust [GradleRunner](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testkit/runner/GradleRunner.html) then I do not appear to have the ability to inspect the project(s) later to actually see if my plugin works.  I have provided sample code below that shows a sample plugin and a junit test.  Does anyone know how I could test this functionality?

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  @Override
  void apply(Project project) {           
    project.extensions.create("myPlugin", MyPluginExtension)
    project.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
       /*
           custom logic that needs to evaluate prior 
           to gradle adding dependencies to project
       */
    }
}
```

The JUnit is provided below:

```
class MyPluginPluginTest {

  private Project project

  @Before
  void setup() {
    project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
    project.repositories.mavenCentral()
    project.apply plugin: 'java'
    project.apply plugin: MyPlugin
  }

  /*
    Test to check whether or not the correct dependency 
    was added to the project when the plugin was evaluated
  */
  @Test 
  void projectHasCheckerFrameworkDependencies() {
     ((ProjectInternal) project).evaluate()

     Set<File> files = project.configurations.getByName('myPlugin').resolve()
     assertNotEquals(0, files.size())
     assertTrue(files.any { it.name.endsWith("myDependency-${project.jarName.version}.jar") })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to gain access to the information I required I added the projectsEvaluated closure to the projectExtensions as follows:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  @Override
  void apply(Project project) {           
    project.extensions.create("myPlugin", MyPluginExtension)
    def projectsEvaluatedClosure = {
      /*
         custom logic that needs to evaluate prior 
         to gradle adding dependencies to project
      */
    }

    project.extensions.add("myPluginProjectsEvaluatedClosure", projectsEvaluatedClosure)
    project.gradle.projectsEvaluated closure
  }
}
```

Now that the projectsEvaluated closure is accessible in the project I executed the closure manually from the test case.  This isn't an ideal solution, but I was able to verify that the code was working properly.